# Inheriting from class with a template parameter friend

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do the following: I have a class and whenever I declare a new instance of this class I want to set a static variable in another class. I'm trying to do it with templates so I can do something like `class C : public D<AA, BB, CC, DD>` (using variadic  parameters). The problem is that the static variable of the classes `AA, BB, CC, DD` (all which share the same base) is protected. So I'm trying make `C` a friend of the classes so it can access the variable.

What I tried is this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    protected:
    static T* t;
    friend T;
};
template <class T>
T* Foo<T>::t = nullptr;
```

First I declared the base class Foo, which has the static variable and the friend declaration. This is meant to be inherited by other classes.

Then I made this:

```
template <class Self, class T> //T = Type derived from Foo
struct Bar
{
    Bar()
    {
        T::t = static_cast<Self*>(this);
    }
};
```

Which is the class that when instantiated will set the static variable in the type `T`.

And this is the final implementation:

```
struct FooDerived;

struct BarDerived : public Bar<BarDerived, FooDerived>
{

};

struct FooDerived : public Foo<BarDerived>
{

};
```

My idea is that:

1. `BarDerived` will set the static `t` in `FooDerived`
2. `FooDerived` inherits `Foo<BarDerived>` which is a friend of `BarDerived`
3. Since `BarDerived` is a friend of `Foo<BarDerived>`, it can access `Foo<BarDerived>::t`

But that doesn't work and I get the following compile error:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Bar<Self, T>::test() [with Self = BarDerived; T = FooDerived]’:
prog.cpp:37:9:   required from here
prog.cpp:11:4: error: ‘BarDerived* Foo<BarDerived>::t’ is protected
 T* Foo<T>::t = nullptr;
    ^
prog.cpp:18:8: error: within this context
   T::t = static_cast<Self*>(this);
        ^
```

(https://ideone.com/jcRcH0)

Did I miss something with the way I expected the templates/friendship to behave?

Comment: The name `T::t` is protected, you cannot access it directly from `Bar<..>` since that class is not a friend of `foo`. You have to make that name accessible to `Bar<..>` via `BarDerived`, or befriend `Bar<..>` directly.

Comment: IMHO the design is quite convoluted.

Comment: @dyp I did this to make the work of creating Bars and their relationships with Foos easier, you think it could be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following: https://ideone.com/RW3xfV

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
protected:
    static T* t;
    template <class Self, class U> //T = Type derived from Foo
    friend struct Bar;
};
```

as it is `Bar` which requires access to `Foo<T>::t`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that BarDerived was responsible for setting Foo::t and not the base.